# OpenERP 7.0. add field to purchase.purchase_order_tree

Tags: python, module, field, odoo

Is posible to add fields to purchase.orde.line "Quantity" (of purchase product) and "Product" ?

I do not need to see in the list of purchases how much it costs but product and product quantity.

I think I have correct xml file inherit and xpath, what I am looking for is a function which add fields to purchase. In my case all purchases will contain onlz one product with one quantity.

Line of purchase product (product_id) and quantity of the purchase product (product_qty).

After I will see in the list of purchases how much of each products and quantity I have.

**purchase_quantity.xml**

```
<record id="view_purchase_inherit_form"  model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">purchase.inherit.form</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_tree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='amount_total']" position="before">
                <field name="quantity_purchase"/>
            </xpath>
        </data> 
    </field>
</record>
```

**__purchase_quantity__.py**

```
from osv import osv, fields
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'
    _columns = {
        'quantity_purchase': fields.related('product_qty',string='Quantity', type='integer')
}
sale_order_line()
```

Do i go right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things leap out here.

1. You don't need the data tags inside the arch field, you just have one or more xpath expressions inside the arch field.
2. Your model is wrong, it should be "purchase.order", "purchase.order.tree is the namne of the base view, not the model name.

Comment: well and how will look code for the field? i have problem how show quantity from purchase order in treeview. i no need recalculate it becouse i have only one order per one purchase.